# Is there a formal distinction between potential and actual infinities?

Tags: mathematical-logic, set-theory, infinity

In modern set theory the difference between actual infinity and potential infinity is often not understood or even denied. Some decades back however mathematicians like Hilbert or Poincaré, let alone Cantor or Fraenkel were fully aware of the difference. My question: Does there exist a formal definition of potential infinity in contrast to actual infinity, and who was the first to give it?

Comment: A near-duplicate is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351529/can-we-formally-distinguish-between-actual-and-potential-infinities. Also, it seems to me that the usual notion of 'computable set' (='recursive set') is a good candidate for the usual modern-day notion of 'potentially infinite set', in some vague philosophical sense.

Comment: It is just this mistaken view, uttered in an upvoted answer there, that I wish to unveil as such. Evidently there is an abyss between pot. and act. and by no means mathematical identity. For instance it is impossible to define a real number by a potentially infinite sequence of digits.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; to clarify in turn: I did not mean to imply any evaluation of the content of the thread I linked. I merely meant to add context and increase connectivity of SE.

Comment: 'Actual' infinity is  stronger than 'potential' and in ZF the  Axiom of Infinity asserts the existence of an infinite set. Analysis however works fine using just 'arbitrarily large' (or small) finite elements which  is equivalent to potential infinity but manages to avoid even its mentioning. Perhaps a formal distinction is not really needed.

Comment: It is generally taken that intuitionist/constructivist axiomatizations of mathematics express potential infinity, whereas the (now) classical ones express actual infinity. Therefore, you can not have a formal distinction within the "modern set theory" (ZFC, I assume), you have to formally  modify some of its axioms, and even the underlying logical framework.

Comment: @Conifold: I think that a farther developed language can define a more primitive one. The language of ZFC is even able to reject the axiom of infinity at all. Further ZFC does not really define actual infinity. At least the axiom of infinity does not yield aleph_0.

Comment: @sand1: In ZFC the axiom of infinity asserts potential infinity. To interpret it as actual infinity is unjustified although it may be argued with the axiom of extensionality. I completely agree with you and Hilbert that for ananlysis potential infinity is fully sufficient. It seems that Zermelo and Fraenkel have been wrong there: "Those who are really serious about rejection of the actual infinite in mathematics should ... do without the whole modern analysis" (Zermelo). "If the attack on the infinite will succeed ... only remnants of mathematics will remain" (Fraenkel).

Comment: If you want to get technical about it, there is no such thing as infinity in modern mathematics. A collection is called infinite if it can be put into bijection with a strict subset of itself, but “infinity” is really better thought of as a way people interpret that property than something that’s actually being defined.

Comment: @Stella Biderman: There is an infinite set given by the axiom of infinity. The only question is how to distinguish the potential infinity required in analysis from the actual infinity of set theory. That is a matter of interpretation - not the fact that mathematics is heavily based on infinity.

Comment: @Wilhelm The axiom of infinity states that there exists a set that is in bijection with a strict subset of itself.

Comment: @Stella Biderman: The axiom of infinity does not state anything about bijective functions. See for instance p. 45 of https://www.hs-augsburg.de/~mueckenh/Transfinity/Transfinity/pdf

Comment: @Wilhelm I guess that depends on how you wish to write it. The way I would right it would involve bijective functions.

Comment: @Stella Biderman: I meant the original formulation by Zermelo and the usual way the axiom is stated. But I would be interested in your approach.

Comment: It took me 10 seconds' worth of reading the Wikipedia entry to be able to summarize this controversy as "whole lot of wanking going on."  I categorically deny this argument has any functional value within mathematics.

Comment: @Wilhelm I dunno, that’s not how we did it in my courses. I can’t speak to what is common beyond the groups I’m familiar with.

Comment: @Conifold Infinity is banana, read here, please (though the issue is not completed yet, sure.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/Kw14wMHdwB8

Comment: @wilhelm I am sorry Sir but I was having trouble understanding your first comment. Are you claiming that "it is impossible to define a real number by a potentially infinite sequence of digits", or are you claiming that this is a mistaken view?

Answer (score 3):

Not "formal" but quite precise: [Aristotle and *apeiron*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-mathematics/index.html#12).

See *Meta*, Book IX ($\Theta$), [1048b10](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0052%3Abook%3D9%3Asection%3D1048b):

> The infinite and the void and all similar things are said to exist potentially
>   and actually in a different sense from that in which many other things are said
>   so to exist, e.g. that which sees or walks or is seen. [...] But the infinite does not exist potentially in the sense that it will ever actually have separate existence; its separateness is only in knowledge. For the fact that division never ceases to be possible gives the result that this actuality exists potentially, but not that it exists separately.

And *Phys*, Book III, 4, 206b17:

> By addition then, also, there is potentially an infinite, namely, what we have
>   described as being in a sense the same as the infinite in respect of division. For it will always be possible to take something *ab extra*. Yet the sum of the parts taken will not exceed every determinate magnitude, just as in the direction of division every determinate magnitude is surpassed and there will always be a smaller part.

And 207a32:

> It is reasonable that there should not be held to be an infinite in respect
>   of addition such as to surpass every magnitude.

Comment: Thank you, but many "modern mathematicians" will not understand this, or disqualify it as purely philosophical. Unfortunately most of them have lost the ability to understand other than formalized text.

Comment: @Wilhelm Can you provide a basis for this statement?

Comment: Hilbert's "On the Infinite" is another classic which I cant resist mentioning here. It ends by saying "logic alone is not sufficient" and explains his Kantian stance.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos: With pleasure, more than many. But space is limited. See for instance the upvoted answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351529/can-we-formally-distinguish-between-actual-and-potential-infinities:  [They] are mathematically indistinguishable. Or P.L. Clark in https://www.hs-augsburg.de/~mueckenh/Transfinity/Transfinity/pdf, p. 11. Or
Dan Christensen: There is no need to formally distinguish actual and potential infinity. It never comes up in real-world mathematics. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.logic/-hsEMkwt6FM%5B1-25%5D

Comment: @Wilhelm Plenty of mathematicians read and understand Aristotle. It seems like there is a person or group of people you wish to fight with the answer to this question. None of the links you’ve provided show that mathematicians cannot understand artistotle. They show that those mathematicians think that there’s no need for a mathematician to distinguish between the two. Those are widely different things.

Comment: @Sella Biderman: Mathematicians who understand Aristotle, Cantor, Fraenkel, Zermelo, Hilbert, Nelson, Feferman, Robinson, Jech, Schechter, etc. cannot think that there is no need to distinguish infinities. "In spite of significant difference between the notions of the potential and actual infinite, where the former is a variable finite magnitude, growing above all limits, the latter a constant quantity fixed in itself but beyond all finite magnitudes, it happens deplorably often that the one is confused with the other." (Cantor) ctd.

Comment: For instance, a function could never show countability of a set or its uncountability unless the domain is finished or complete. Simple example: The diagonal argument fails in potential infinity because you never reach the completeness required for a decision.

Comment: @Wilhelm what do you mean the diagonal argument fails “in potential infinity”? Do you mean the counterfactual “if the natural numbers were potentially infinite then the diagonal argument would not work”? Do you mean “if you’re only allowed to carry out potentially infinitely many steps then the diagonal argument fails”? Do you mean something else?

Comment: @Stella Biderman: The diagonal argument proves that the complete set N can absorb only a subset of R. Why should we believe this if there does not exist a complete set N?

Answer (score 2):

The distinction between potential and actual infinities was Aristotle's clever solution to Zeno's paradoxes. The idea was that while we can mentally divide segments in half indefinitely actualizing the resulting sequence, which is what Zeno does in Dichotomy, is in error. From Metaphysics VIII.8:

> "*Though there are infinitely many halves in a continuum, these are potential and not actual... So the reply we have to make to the question whether it is possible to traverse infinitely many parts... is that there is a sense in which it is possible, and which it is not. If they exist actually, it is impossible; but if they exist potentially, it is possible.*"

However, after the invention of calculus alternative resolutions became available, and Cantor's work convinced many mathematicians that other "paradoxes of infinity" could be dealt with as well, see [Why did Cantor (and others) use $\mathfrak{c}$ for the continuum?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/2419/55). Moreover, Cantor developed a theory of actualized infinities which was seen as fruitful (Hilbert's "*no one shall expel us from the Paradise that Cantor has created*" is oft-quoted). The actual infinity is built into the standard axiomatizations of set theory, therefore it can not be distinguished from potential infinity *within* them. To do the distinguishing one needs *alternative axiomatizations* of mathematics. This underscores Hilbert's idea of axioms as implicit definitions of terms.

The underlying conceptions were developed by intuitionists, mainly Brouwer and Weyl, see [Brouwer and Weyl: The Phenomenology and Mathematics of the Intuitive Continuum by Atten et al.](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/1874/26962/preprint211.pdf?sequence=1.) Poincaré, Borel, Baire, Lebesgue and other so-called proto-intuitionists anticipated these ideas earlier, see [Did Poincaré say that set theory is a disease?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/6042/55) (not exactly).  Here is Weyl's informal description of his and Brouwer's conception in Philosophy of Mathematics and Natural Science (1949):

> "*The notion of sequence changes its meaning: it no longer signifies a sequence determined by some law or other, but rather one that is created step by step by free acts of choice, and thus remains in statu nascendi. This ‘becoming’ selective sequence represents the continuum, or the variable, while the sequence determined ad infinitum by a law represents the individual real number falling into the continuum. The continuum no longer appears, to use Leibniz’s language, as an aggregate of fixed elements but as a medium of free ‘becoming’*".

In [Das Kontinuum (1918)](https://quantitability.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/hermann-weyl-the-continuum-a-critical-examination.pdf) Weyl undertook an intuitionistic reconstruction of classical analysis based on these infinities in becoming. Weyl's reconstruction was first of many. In 1930 Heyting formalized  [intuitionistic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic), which allowed to give full formal expression to Brouwer's and Weyl's potential infinities. It turned out that it is not enough to alter set theory axioms (in particular, axioms of infinity and choice have to be dropped), but to also drop the law of excluded middle, which allows reasoning by contradiction. Indeed, if the infinite is never "completed" certain statements about it can not have truth values one way or the other. More recent developments in this direction, like [Bishop's constructive analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_analysis), usually go under the name of constructivism (to avoid Kantian associations), see also [Constructive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_set_theory). While a minority position among mathematicians constructivism proved to be a lasting presence.

Comment: Thank you, but I need a *formal* statement in order to convince modern set theorists. By the way, the actual infinite is not built into the Peano axioms. So what part of Zermelo's axiom "exists { } and with $a$ exists {$a$}" yields finished infinity? Hilbert was enchanted by actual infinity but at the end of the paper praising Cantor's paradise he summarized, somewhat cooling down: "The infinite is nowhere realized; it is neither present in nature nor admissible as the foundation of our rational thinking."  I for my person prefer rational thinking.

Comment: @Wilhelm What convinced most mathematicians was reconstruction of mathematics based on set theory with Cantor's actual infinities. Constructivist reconstructions are too restrictive to be widely appealing, although [Rodin](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.1478) has an interesting new approach. Finished infinity is given by ["there exists inductive set"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity), or something similar. Peano axioms combined with intuitionistic logic presumably express potential infinity only.

Comment: "There exists an inductive set" alone does not yet make infinity finished. It could also have been said by Peano. But all that would be much easier to discuss if we had a formal definition of what we may colloquially express as: A set $S$ is pot. inf. if "every subset has a proper superset in $S$". A set $S$ is act. inf. if "not every subset has a proper superset in $S$ ".

Comment: @Wilhelm Peano arithmetic does not allow talk about sets, but as long as the logic is classical its countable infinity is presumably actual. Your proposal is called [Dedekind infinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set), it comes apart from the inductive conception in models of ZF.

Answer (score 0):

A continuous function can be characterized as a function where the output can be determined to any finite accuracy using only finite information about the input. (By finite information, I mean accuracy. Stupid English language!)

Whether an infinity is "potential" or "actual" depends exactly on what you do with it. A real number is an infinite object; it's got infinitely many digits. Certain operations on real numbers are feasible, whereas others are not. For instance, it's clearly *not* feasible to decide if a real number is equal to $0$, because that would require knowing every digit of the number. It *is* feasible to multiply a real number by $2$, because this can be determined to accuracy $\epsilon$ by reading only finitely many digits of the input.

Whether an operation is feasible can be captured either by computability or continuity. Topology and computability theory define the notions of continuous function and computable function. If a function is discontinuous or uncomputable then you've got an actual infinity. Also, continuity and computability are fairly similar in practice.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but too long for a comment. It shows the direction where the answer should be looked for.

A collection or class $C$ is potentially infinite if and only if for every subset $A$ there is a subset $B$ such that $A$ is a *proper* subset of $B$. Otherwise $C$ is finite or actually infinite.

$C$ is potentially infinite $\Leftrightarrow \forall A\subseteq C$ $\exists B \subseteq C:A\subset B$.

Remark: The complete collection or set of all natural numbers does not exist in potential infinity. The complete real interval $[0, 1]$ does not exist in potential infinity (for instance, because the complete collection of unit fractions does not exist).

Comment: There is something wrong with the definition: if A is allowed to be C then no set satisfies it, C is not a proper subset of anything, if A is not allowed to be C then every set satisfies it, one can always take B=C.

Comment: @Conifold: It is tricky. A subset $A$ or $B$ cannot be the potentially infinite class $C$ because the latter does not exist as a completed entity (= set). Only if $C$ is finite or actually infinite, then $A = C$ is possible and the criterion gives the answer not "potentially infinite", i.e., finite or actually infinite.

Comment: It is circular. You are using the distinction which you are trying to define to make the definition.

Comment: @Conifold: I am not trying to define potential infinity. I am giving a *formal* criterion. Of course I give it so that the distinction that is usually described colloquially is resulting.

Comment: That is well and good, but so far you defined nothing and gave no formal (or any) criterion. For a criterion one should not have to consult you on what constitutes or does not constitute a "completed" subset before it is "formally" spelled out. At best, you have some vague intuition. You can try to do something inductively, but I see no obvious way to unwind your circle. Or you can try to embed this into some list of axioms implicitly describing relations between finite, potential and actual infinite. But you'll need a lot more axioms to make it viable.

Comment: @Conifold: There is no circle and no intuition. Simply apply any any set you like as $C$. If it sastifis the criterion then it is potentially infinite. Otherwise it is finite or actually infinite. Try it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72753/discussion-between-conifold-and-wilhelm).